# How to get value of selected radioButton of buttonGroup

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

How to get value of selected `radioButton`?
I tried using `buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand()` (as posted in some of answers here) but it is not working.
Also, i am temporarily using this code but i want to know is this a good practice or not?

```
//Consider that maleRButton and femaleRButton are two radioButtons of 
//same buttonGroup
String getGender()
{
    if(maleRButton.isSelected())
    {
        return "Male";
    }
    else if(femaleRButton.isSelected())
    {
        return "Female";
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried using buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand()

That approach will work, but for some reason it looks like you manually need to set the action command when you create the button. For example:

```
JRadioButton maleButton = new JRadioButton( "Male" );
maleButton.setActionCommand( maleButton.getText() );
```

This acutally seems like a bit of a bug to me since usually the action command defaults to the text if the action command is not set.

Answer (score 5):

If you have several buttons you probably should do it this way :

```
String getSelectedButton()
{  
    for (Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = buttonGroup1.getElements(); buttons.hasMoreElements();) {
        AbstractButton button = buttons.nextElement();
        if (button.isSelected()) {
                return button.getText();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String gender=group.getSelection().getActionCommand();`

It will work but it show null value.

Comment: I just set radio1.setActionCommand("button1") and it will work  (radio1is my JRadioBurron name)

Answer (score 0):

```
int selectedRadioButtonID = radio_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
// If nothing is selected from Radio Group, then it return -1
if (selectedRadioButtonID != -1) {
RadioButton selectedRadioButton = findViewById(selectedRadioButtonID);
String selectedRadioButtonText = selectedRadioButton.getText().toString();
answerList.add(selectedRadioButtonText);
} else {
Toast.makeText(this, "select radio button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
}
```

[For Deatils, check this](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-radio-group-get-selected.html)